# Integration Testing with Kitchen CI

Tags: continuous-integration, chef-infra, integration-testing, chef-solo, test-kitchen

I have cookbooks to deploy infrastructure to azure cloud. My cookbooks create required VMs, setup SQL Servers, attach disks to VM and some software installation.

I want that Kitchen CI itself:

1. Verify that my resources have spawned correctly or not
2. Validate that configurations are done correctly or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by #1 you mean to check if Chef actually works, don't worry, we have our own test suites for that. What you want focus on is #2, checking that the side effects of your recipes are what you expect. As for how to use Test Kitchen, we have some guides at https://learn.chef.io and the main TK website at https://kitchen.ci/.